# Excel rows does not show overs 65536 if export from Frotaccounting ERP

Tags: php, excel

I am using FrontAccountion version 1.1.0. Some of my report has over 65536 rows. But if i export report in excel format, it does not show over 65536 rows. Because FrontAccountion use Excel-97-2003.   Excel-97-2003 does not support over 65536 rows.
I have downloaded latest version of FrontAccountion. But latest version also use Excel-97-2003 for export.

Now how can i solved my problem. If any idea please help me.

Thanks
Nashir Uddin

Comment: Create several xls-files

Comment: Try to export to another format (e.g. csv) or wait for your question over here to be answered: http://frontaccounting.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=6793